# JavaScript syntax

Tags: javascript, syntax

In another question answered here I found the following [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) code:

```
function _dom_trackActiveElement(evt) {
    if (evt && evt.target) { 
        document.activeElement = evt.target == document ? null : evt.target;
    }
}
```

But this syntax is unknown to me, could someone explain exactly what

```
document.activeElement = evt.target == document ? null : evt.target;
```

does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`? :` is the conditional operator, sometimes called the "ternary operator". As an example, `a ? b : c` will return `b` if `a` is `true`, and `c` otherwise.

Your code will assign `null` to `document.activeElement` if `evt.target == document`. Otherwise, `evt.target` will be assigned.

Comment: It is the conditional operator, not the ternary operator. It is _a_ ternary operator, since it takes three operands.

Answer (score 2):

This is Ternary Operator, [here is more info about it.](http://www.hscripts.com/tutorials/javascript/ternary.php)

Its prototype is like this:

```
 (expression) ? true : false
```

Example:

```
 (myvar == 10) ? document.write('yes it is equal to 10') : document.write('no it is not equal to 10')
```

Your condition can be re-written like this too which is essentially the same:

```
if (evt.target == document)
{
  document.activeElement = null;
}
else
{
  document.activeElement = evt.target;
}
```

Hope this if-else condition makes it easier for you to understand what Ternary operator is all about. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a ternary operator, similar to that in java. Its saying that if evt.target==document then activeElement is null, otherwise activeElement is evt.target.

Answer (score 1):

It is the ternary operator. It might be easier if I parenthesise it for you:

```
document.activeElement = ((evt.target == document) ? null : evt.target);
```

The basic format is:

```
something_boolean ? if_true_return_this : else_return_this;
```

So you can either use it like an if-else statement, or for assignment.

Answer (score 1):

That syntax is the [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/Conditional_Operator) (also known as ternary operator). The expression

```
expr1 ? expr2 : expr3
```

evaluates to the evaluated value of *expr2* if the evaluated value of *expr1* is true or to the evaluated value of *expr3* otherwise.

So in your example

```
evt.target == document ? null : evt.target
```

will evaluate to *null* if `evt.target == document` is true or to `evt.target` otherwise. That means *null* is assigned to `document.activeElement` if `evt.target == document` is true and otherwise `evt.target` is assigned to `document.activeElement`:

```
if (evt.target == document) {
    document.activeElement = null;
} else {
    document.activeElement = evt.target;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the [conditional operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_operator), which  wikipeida explains as

> condition ? value if true : value if false

It is easier to read with brackets, as it makes the order of evaluation clearer

```
document.activeElement = (evt.target == document ? null : evt.target);
```

The above line can be expanded expanded to

```
if ( evt.target == document ){
    document.activeElement = null;
}else{
    document.activeElement = evt.target;
}
```

In other words, it assigns the result of the conditional expression to `document.activeElement`.